# Conditionally Merging JSON Schema Properties

Tags: json, intellisense, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to create a JSON schema to validate YAML for some VSCode intellisense. What I'm trying to do is choose the correct subschema to use for a property in the main schema based on an adjacent key's value.

Some JSON examples:

```
[
  {
    "name": "doesntmatter",
    "matchMe": "stringToMatch:123whatever",
    "mergeMe": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
  }
]
```

```
[
  {
    "name": "doesntmatter",
    "matchMe": "anotherStringToMatch:123whatever",
    "mergeMe": {
        "anotherKey": "valueSomething",
        "anotherKey2": "cheese"
    }
  }
]
```

So I need to choose the correct schemas for the `mergeMe` objects based on the substring match of `matchMe`. After following a bunch of answers, I'm at a point where I can either make it match multiple, and error my linter, or match none, but an online validator says it's ok (except nothing matches as the `required` fields aren't triggering).

I moved my sub-schemas to be merged into `definitions` to reference them, and then used an if/then to match. That worked with one, but then I tried to expand it to do the tree matching, and I can't get that to work. Someone said that I should wrap my if/thens in an `allOf` (I'm not sure why that would work since surely not all of them would match?). Changing it to an `anyOf` makes none of them match and I get no intellisense. Nor do I really understand why I should wrap single if/thens or thens in `allOf`s.

The idea is that based on the pattern it uses a `definitions` schema to match the `mergeMe` property, but the conditional logic isn't quite right. Thinned schema below:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "array",
    "title": "The root schema",
    "description": "The root schema comprises the entire JSON document.",
    "default": [],
    "additionalItems": true,
    "definitions": {
        "stringToMatch": {
            "$id": "#/definitions/stringToMatch",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "key1": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "key1"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": true
        },
        "anotherStringToMatch": {
            "$id": "#/definitions/anotherStringToMatch",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "key2": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "key2"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": true
        }
    },
    "items": {
        "$id": "#/items",
        "type": "object",
        "title": "main schema",
        "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
        "default": {},
        "examples": [],
        "required": [
            "name",
            "matchMe",
            "mergeMe"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "$id": "#/items/name",
                "type": "string",
                "title": "The name schema",
                "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
                "default": "",
                "examples": []
            },
            "matchMe": {
                "$id": "#/items/matchMe",
                "type": "string",
                "title": "The matchMe schema",
                "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
                "default": "",
                "examples": []
            }
        },
        "allOf": [
            {
                "if": {
                    "properties": {
                        "matchMe": {
                            "pattern": "^stringToMatch:[0-9.]+"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "mergeMe": {
                                    "$ref": "#/definitions/stringToMatch"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "if": {
                    "properties": {
                        "gear": {
                            "pattern": "^anotherStringToMatch:[0-9.]+"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "mergeMe": {
                                    "$ref": "#/definitions/anotherStringToMatch"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "additionalProperties": true
    }
}
```

What I want in JS would look something like

```
const schema = { name, matchMe }
if (matchMe == "string1") schema.mergeMe = ...subschema1;
else if (...)
else if (...)
```

but I just can't really work it out. Can someone help?

Edit: jsonschema.dev playground - the idea being if I specify the food as prefixed by "fruit" I have to give it "pips" and "berry", whereas if I specify "vegetable" I have to give it a totally differet schema, and they don't overlap.
https://jsonschema.dev/s/pHzGo

Comment: It’s really hard to reason your schema and instance when you use non-real values. Please can you replace your pretend values with real values? I know that seems silly but it provides context that might be helpful. Bonus points if you can provide a few https://jsonschema.dev links showing your problem.

Comment: Sure sure - totally understandable. I've tried to create a small example using fruit and veg (edited at the bottom of the question).

Comment: Could you provide some examples of instances that are not validating as expected. You're on the right track. I'm guessing you just have a few edge cases to smooth out.

Comment: Currently none of the examples validate as expected, I'm afraid - they're a mix of what I had at the time of posting and what I have at time of editing in the jsonschema.dev link, with what _should_ be validated for a schema that is incorrect. I've discovered that the "pattern" condition in the "if" isn't actually matching, having subbed the ref out for simple "required"s to see more clearly what's going on.

Comment: I'm actually not entierly sure this is a json-schema question anymore - when brought down to a basic level of "if type is string" then () else require something - it clearly validates ok in online validators, but VSCode simply refuses to validate a property in an "if" block, although it can then require the same property to be a different type in the next "else" block.

Answer (score 1):

This actually ended up being a bug in the VSCode YAML extension that was ingesting my schema, causing the `if` blocks to not evaluate, and has been [raised](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/393), fixed and released.